# How can I use CSS or JS to make some text inputs display a help icon inside the input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, icons

I don't much like external help icons, as they hinder consistent layout, and would much prefer to place the help icon inside inputs marked with e.g. a `with-help` class. They would look something like this:

[image: Input with interal help icon]

I would also much prefer that the 'icon' be an SVG shape. Is that possible with CSS, or would I need JS to add the SVG shape to all such inputs?

Comment: does the help icon need to be clickable? Or is it just a look

Comment: It must be clickable. I don't see much use for it otherwise. But nearly anything can be made clickable.

Comment: then using JUST css won't help. Most likely you'll need to attach an additional div inside that box and have an onclick event handler on it

Comment: I know css probably won't help with the onclick, but a simple jQuery 1-liner can make the image clickable, without any extra div, I'm also going to look at Bootstrap's `data-toggle` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at below code. change the value of `border-width: 0 30px 30px 0;` to change the size of triangle, and change `text-indent:16px;` to align question mark.

```css
.help{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
input{
  padding:10px;
}
.help a:before{
  content: "?";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  display:block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 30px 30px 0;
  border-color: transparent #007bff transparent transparent;
  text-align:right;
  text-indent:16px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="help">
  <input type="text" >
  <a href=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Very clever use of `border-width`. Thank you!